# C# Regex Match from TextBox.Text?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

so I'm having issues with finding regex match in textbox2.text (the text looks like a javascript file)
here is my code:

```
string file = Regex.Match(textBox2.Text, @"rl='(.*)'", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[0].Value;
```

I'm trying to find what is between `rl='` & `'` but I'm getting what is between + rl=' and ' the "()" don't seem to work? >.<

Any idea what is the issue?

Comment: Try non-greedy quantifier: (.*?) instead of (.*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this regex pattern,

```
(?<=rl=').*(?=')
```

See **[Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Width Assertions.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**

sample demo

[image]

Comment: `.*` doesnt work here..should use `.*?` else would match greedily

Comment: @Anirudha it depends on what you want, if you have text, `rl='the address is st paul's village'` will result `the address is st paul`. using `.*?` will make it lazy.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to find what is between rl=' & '

You should use this regex then

```
@"(?<=rl\=').*?(?=')"
```

This regex tells the engine to match 0-n number of characters i.e`(.*?)` which has `rl='` at the beginning of it i.e`(?<=rl\=')` and end's with a `'` `i.e(?=')`